# Bile storage and secretion

Tags: human-physiology, liver, bile

I know that the liver has left and right hepatic ducts that unite forming the common hepatic duct that then unites with the cystic duct of the gall bladder forming the common bile duct which unites with the pancreatic duct forming the ampulla of Vater that opens in the duodenum.

I also know that the liver secretes its bile which is stored in the gall bladder.

My question is how come the liver secretes its bile via the hepatic ducts and stores it in the gall bladder at the same time?

Comment: Because there are two main functions of bile in the body, and in this way, both can be achieved. Googling functions of biliary system should give you the answer,. If you edit to provide a quote and a link to the source(s) you found, and still don't understand, please explain what you don't understand, receive a more complete answer. Thanks.